# How can I have an html table where a vertical scroll bar appears only if larger than screen

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a web page with a html table in the middle of the page.  Sometimes there are many rows so I want the table (not the full page) to have a vertical scroll bar added.  If the table doesn't go off the page I don't want the vertical scroll bar to show.   I also don't want to hardcode a specifc px for the height of the table.

What is the best way of achieving this?  I need to support back to IE7

Comment: My answer should be adaptable to whatever the situation is, since `vh` gives you a unit based on the window height, but I'm still unsure what you mean by "starts in the middle of the page". If you need a more specific demo, I would need to see exactly what you have already.

Comment: After asking around, it seems likely that you will want to use javascript for backwards compatibility. I have updated my answer with a demo of that also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On updated browsers, you can use `vh` to set the table height according to the window height and fallback to `px` for browsers that don't support `vh`:

```
/* wrap your table in this */
.table-wrap {
  max-height: 300px;
  max-height: 70vh;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/OWewECAW/6/edit)**

Here's a demo with jQuery that you might be interested in. It's not worth including jQuery just for this when it could be easily accomplished with vanilla js. This is just a quick sample. **http://jsbin.com/OWewECAW/7/edit**

```
$wrap = $('.table-wrap');
var offset = $wrap.offset();
var bottom = offset.top + $wrap.height();
var w = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
var newHeight = $wrap.height() - (bottom - w);
$wrap.css('max-height', newHeight);
```

Comment: but if it starts in the middle of the page, isn't max height too big here?  don't i want max-height minus top of table?  Also, as stated i wanted to avoid a hardcoded height px

Comment: @leora I updated with a demo. The `max-height` with `px` is just a fallback for browsers that don't support `vh`.